# Using crc32 over md5 for hashing memcached keys

Tags: php, hash, memcached, md5, crc32

We currently use MD5 to hash keys that we want to lookup in memcached.

A basic example being:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = 1";
$key = md5($sql);

if (!$results = $memcache->get($key)) {
    $results = $db->query($sql);
    $memcache->set($key, $results);
}
```

The key sizes are all 32 bytes as it uses MD5 to hash the key.

We are considering using crc32 instead to hash the key to save memory e.g:

```
$key = hash('crc32', $sql);
```

This generates a key of only 8 bytes.

Is this a good enough solution to replace MD5 as the key hash? Is there an increase in potential collision's with keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read http://bretm.home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/8.html (TL;DR: "CRC32 was never intended for hash table use. There is really no good reason to use it for this purpose, and I recommend that you avoid doing so").

Do you have that many unique queries that it warrants switching to something else besides MD5? If so, consider something more suitable besides CRC32, like [MurmurHash](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/) or [CityHash](https://code.google.com/p/cityhash/).

Comment: MurmurHash seems to be generating 32 bytes keys similar to MD5 is this normal?

Comment: MurmurHash3 (the latest) comes in 32-bit and 128-bit versions. Which implementation are you using? (and how are you using it?)

Comment: The 32-bit version, I installed the MurmurHash3 PHP extension and ran `echo murmurhash3('test', 4);` and it generates a 32 byte string which is not the intention, I'm looking for shorter keys.

Comment: That seems to work better, keys are essentially just numbers right? Is this better than MD5 to ensure uniqueness and collission safe?

Comment: The keys are just numbers, yes. You could make even smaller keys using `base_convert($murmurhashresult, 10, 36)` if you like. And no, it's not better than MD5, it's better than CRC32.

Comment: Bret's study is flawed! See https://github.com/Michaelangel007/crc32/blob/master/README.md#crc32-hashing-confusion

Comment: @minexew even so, given that apparently "almost everyone" doesn't implement CRC32 incorrectly, using an alternative still seems like a good decision ;D